# What is the difference between Kurzweil Mark Pro 1, 2, and 3 Pianos

Tags: piano

I'm only interested in the piano tone and feel as compared to a good acoustic piano. Are there reasons to pay twice the money for Kurzweil Mark 3 vs Mark 1?

Both seem to have the same hammer action design and dimensions, but I haven't tried playing either and am wondering if someone here has had an experience with these.

Comment: I'm not competent to answer your question, but when I was buying a piano for myself I had a lot of thoughts between Yamaha and Korg- but I made a decision after 30 minutes in a store where I could try out both. Maybe that would also be an option for you?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not exceptionally familiar with digital piano designs and was hoping to find some new ideas as it relates to the above. I also feel that it's a useful question to have posted here.

Comment: But of course it is! I have favourited it myself after all... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most significant difference between these three options appears to be the power of the built-in sound system.

Mark-Pro ONEiF: Built-in, 15 watt rms per channel stereo amplifier:
(2) 4x6" full-range drivers

Mark-Pro TWOi: Built-in, 30 watt rms per channel stereo amplifier:
(2x6.5" woofers; 2x2" tweeters)

Mark-Pro THREEi: 80-Watt Amplification: 2 x 40 Watts RMS Per Channel 
4 Speakers: 2 x 6.5 inch (woofers), 2 x 2.5 inch (tweeters)

There are other differences; the number of selectable sounds; the number of drum patterns; the number of sequencer recordings; but if your intention is to play it as a piano, the amplification and speakers would seem to be the important thing.

The keyboard quality, and the quality of the built-in sounds, I would guess is the same on all three.

Comment: Ended up getting the pro 1. The piano would have to cost 3 times as much to match my own speakers, and it would be infinitely more expensive to match my collection of just the free vst instruments.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one experience.

I had gotten an SP 88x a few years back in 2004.  The action was good enough for me not to notice any memory wear or such.

Basically it's been working top-notch ever since I bought it.

I didn't go for anything else because I was looking to learn on weighted keys.  Midi, etc, wasn't a priority.

If you are comp-inclined, midi in and out were there.  I'll be happy to answer any more questions relating to my particular experience.